# Why won't my Kentico v9.0 website display in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, content-management-system, kentico

I've recently upgraded from Kentico v8.2 to Kentico v9.0. In Kentico v8.2 I was able to view the site in IE11, Firefox and Chrome. Since the upgrade to Kentico v9.0 I can only view the website in IE11.

In Chrome and Firefox I get the message "The web site doesn't contain any content. Sign in to administration and edit the content."

If I sign into Administration using Chrome or Firefox the administration tiles are all present and it works as expected. It's just the user website that doesn't display any content.

I found a similar problem here http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/the-web-site-doesn-t-contain-any-content-sign-in-to-administration-and-edit-the-content although they appeared to have no access to their website in any browser. I tried the suggested remedy of clearing out the temporary ASP NET folders but it didn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone know what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: A few things to start with: clear browser cache, check domain aliases, try preview mode, try switching cultures...try adding ?viewmode=livesite to the live url...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but they didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has probably to do with the default language settings of the browser. Try to add the ?lang=xx-xx querystring. Replace xx-xx with the culture (for example en-gb) that is available/translated in the content tree.

To resolve this try one of the following:

- in the "Content" settings enable "Combine with default culture"
- change the "Visitor culture" from "automatic" to a culture that has been translated
- publish or remove the not translated content

Comment: The ?lang=en-US worked. Curiously when I changed the region settings in Chrome to en-US in response to an earlier suggestion it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I found that just using ?lang=en-US once fixed the issue permanently. The website works correctly without the lang parameter, even after a browser and IIS restart

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you clear the cookies, check default visitor culture, make sure that in this culture your pages has your page template, not the default one from blank page.

Comment: Thanks. I tried these but they didn't fix it. I find it curious that the Admin interface works but the site doesn't